# How do I run a GO executable?

Tags: go

I was trying not to use the default go workspace, but to create a separate workspace location. So I did the following:

1. Created a folder, say "/Users/user_name/some_path/go_files/"
2. Created 3 directories in that folder - `src`, `pkg` and `bin`
3. Created a go file called "hello_world.go" inside "/Users/user_name/some_path/go_files/src"
4. Exported the GOPATH variable to "/Users/user_name/some_path/go_files"
5. Built the executable in 2 ways: `go build src/hello_world.go` and `cd src` `go build hello_word.go`
6. The above generated 2 executables - 1 in `go_files/src` and the other in `go_files`
7. However, running either of them gives an error saying: `package hello_world is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/hello_world)`

I tried to run the executable using `go run hello_world`. How do I resolve this? How do I run an executable?

Please note that I can do a `go run hello_world.go` from inside `src` or a `go run src/hello_world.go`, but I want to know how to run the executable.

Comment: FYI `src` is where you should put your packages, not source files directly. Also, do check out [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code).

Comment: "package X is not in GOROOT" is a compiler error, not a runtime error, so you can't get that when you run the compiled binary. It can't be a runtime error because Go programs can be executed just fine without Go installed. This error occurs because there is no dot in the import path. I strongly suggest you use modules instead of GOPATH as explained in "How to Write Go Code".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, running either of them gives an error saying: package hello_world is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/hello_world)

You haven't actually said what you're doing to provoke this error, but it sounds like you're almost certainly running `go run hello_world`. Once you've build an executable, Go (the language) and `go` (the command) are no longer involved. Binaries run independently of their compiler, which may be surprising to you if you're coming from an interpreted language background.

You run any given executable by typing its name (if it's in your path) or by typing the path to it (ie `./hello_world`) and then pressing "return".

Comment: However, to run Java jars, we need the `java` command as well. Is this because the Java jars are essentially byte codes, and still need the JVM for interpretation to machine language?